# Resolving transitive dependency

Tags: maven

I have a simplified **war** project as below:

- my war project depends on project B
- project B has direct runtime dependency on google.guava library

Now I have problem with resolving the dependency on the guava library

1. when I do *mvn package*, the guava library **is not** included in the WEB-INF/lib directory
2. when I do *mvn dependency:copy-dependencies*, the guava library **is** included in the dependency directory
3. when I do *mvn dependency:tree* I can't see the guava library within the tree

Does anyone know why the guava library is not packaged within the war file as expected? What is difference between copying dependencies and packaging them in war?. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven 3 do the trick. I've used Maven 2.2 until now.